# How to use the DATE_ADD doctrine update query with 3 days

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a task Entity which has the start date, while updating need to add 3 days with start date field.

Raw SQlite query : `update table_name set  start_date = date(start_date, '+3 day')`
 works fine but the same need to be implemented in symfony doctrine way.

How do add db expression on the createQueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Add in the entity construct $start_date = new DateTime('+3 days')